# spring cloud stream - RabbitmQ - concurrent consumers

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

Using spring cloud stream with RabbitMQ. I am trying to have a consumer which consumes messages concurrently. Below properties are set, but it is not working. I am missing any required properties (using version Brooklyn.SR3)?

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.channel.consumer.acknowledgementMOde = None
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.channel.consumer.prefetch = 50
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel.consumer.concurrency =50
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.channel.consumer.maxConcurrency = 50
```

Comment: Define "not working" - I just pasted your configs into a simple app and I see 50 container threads in the debugger. BTW `acknowledgementMOde` is misspelled.

Comment: It worked for me now. My mistake, given incorrect channel name which failed to create multiple consumers. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: BTW the 'spring.cloud.stream.bindings.channel.consumer.concurrency=50' config would already be enough to make the consumer concurrent

Comment: @MarvinRichter I need to auto scale consumers. So I set concurrency=2 and maxConcurrency=10. Put infinite while loop inside StreamListener function. But I couldn't see consumer scaling. While SimpleMessageListenerContainer object has been initialized with currect values. Have you tried this?